# Stop form from submitting values to php file if empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to stop my form from submitting and taking an action on going to another php file if the form has no  value from at least one of its variables.

```
<form id="advform" class="" action="advancedsearching.php" method="GET"  onsubmit = "return validate()" autocomplete="off"   >
                <div class="modal-header align-items-center justify-content-center py-2 ">              
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Advanced Search</h4>
        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body  ">              
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Author:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ISBN:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="isbn" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Publisher:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="publisher" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Keyword:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="keyword" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center  ">
                    
        
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"   value="Search" style="width:100%;border:1px solid black;">
                </div>
            </form>
```

tried adding

```
 <script>
function validate() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("advform").value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter a Value");
        return false;
    };
}
</script>
```

but it is still submitting

Comment: Why not use a `required` attribute? Also, what have you tried to check **why** your approach is not working as expected?

Comment: Hello, i already solved the problem but for your question why i did not used required attribute, its because i want users to input a word on any of the field, and they can leave other field with no value, but for the form to submit , at least one of the field should have a value .else the form will submit and will redirect users to a search result for "blank" . what ive done here is before submitting all the values, the values will be concatenated to a string variable, and if that string variable is equal to ="" , the form will not submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function validate() {
        var inputs = document.getElementById('advform').getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        {
            if (inputs[i].type != "submit" && inputs[i].value != "") 
            {
                return true;
            }

            alert("Please Enter a Value");

            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<form id="advform" class="" action="advancedsearching.php" method="GET"  onsubmit = "return validate()" autocomplete="off"   >
                <div class="modal-header align-items-center justify-content-center py-2 ">              
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Advanced Search</h4>
        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body  ">              
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Author:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ISBN:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="isbn" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Publisher:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="publisher" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Keyword:</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="keyword" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center  ">
                    
        
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"   value="Search" style="width:100%;border:1px solid black;">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: this makes all the field "required", what I want to do is to check if all the fields are blank, if all fields are blank the form will not submit, else, if any of the fields has a value, at least one, the form will submit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this using an event assigned to the submit button:

```
document.getElementById("submitBtnId").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // event.preventDefault() will stop your submit.
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

To proceed submitting you can use:

```
 event.currentTarget.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because you have the id in your form, it should be in the input that you want to validate.

other way its to use the required Attribute in the input

```
<input type="text"  name="publisher" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off"  autocomplete="false" required>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: this doesn't work for me, i want people from choosing to write on any field or if they want to leave any field blank, its just i don't want to submit the form and redirect to the display result page if the fields are completely empty

Comment: so it should be at lest one field with information? it dosent matter which?

Comment: yes sir , any of the field